# Load Testing Service: Kafka Consumer, Aerospike Reader

Tags: performance, apache-kafka, load-testing, aerospike, locust

I have a service with the following architecture.

1. It consumes messages from one Kafka topic.
2. It reads records from [Aerospike](https://aerospike.com/).
3. It puts enriched message to another Kafka topic.

Here is the schema.

[image: service schema]

We're using [Locust](https://locust.io/) for load testing. The question is how to test
`Enricher` for the maximum load? I could send messages to Kafka topic. But as far as I understood, I would test Kafka itself but not the `Enricher`. Because the service cannot consume more messages that it is able to proceed. By the way, Aerospike interaction is also important. I have to be sure that the amount of reads won't break the cluster.

So, what are the common practices to test Kafka consumer in such scenario?

Comment: For those who interested I gave a solution for that in [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72202850/locust-python-kafka-consumer-in-a-separate-thread/72216824#72216824).

Answer (score 1):

> But as far as I understood, I would test Kafka itself but not the Enricher.

Why do you say that? If the purpose of your application is to process the queue, then putting a bunch of messages there seems like an entirely reasonable approach.

Such a test is of course dependant on Kafka being fast (faster than your application), but that is most likely the case.

Specifically, have a look at https://github.com/SvenskaSpel/locust-plugins/blob/master/examples/kafka_ex.py

But you’ll want to measure the processing time somewhere else (either in your app, or by comparing the time a message was placed on the input topic to when it arrived in the output topic)

Like with most queue/batch-oriented applications your performance is probably best expressed in transactions/s or the amount of time it takes to process X number of messages (latency may also be important but usually less so)

Answer (score -1):

Possible using [Torque](https://db.apache.org/torque/torque-5.1/developer-info/test-project.html) as is suggest in [Finding Order in Chaos: How We Automated Performance Testing with Torque](https://blog.dream11engineering.com/finding-order-in-chaos-how-we-automated-performance-testing-with-torque-6eb63706fcea).

Comment: Excuse me, but could you explain the process to me? How exactly should I load test `Enricher` in my case?