# Locust Python: Kafka Consumer in a separate thread

Tags: python, multithreading, apache-kafka, load-testing, locust

I'm using [Locust](https://locust.io/) for load testing. I want to register a Kafka consumer in separate thread to measure the time of message processing. Here is what I got now:

```py
def register_kafka_consumer(topic, environment):
    def poll():
        request_type = 'KAFKA_MESSAGE_CONSUMED'
        consumer = Consumer({
            'bootstrap.servers': bootstrap_servers,
            'group.id': group_id
        })
        consumer.subscribe([topic])
        logging.getLogger().info("Consumer subscribed to topic '%s': %s", topic, consumer)
        try:
            while True:
                msg = consumer.poll()
                if msg is not None and not msg.error():
                    # diff_millis calculation
                    environment.events.request.fire(
                        request_type=request_type,
                        name=topic,
                        response=msg.value(),
                        response_time=diff_millis,
                    )
        except Exception:
            logging.getLogger().error("Error during polling message for consumer: %s",
                                      str(consumer), exc_info=True)
        finally:
            logging.getLogger().info("Kafka consumer closed: %s", str(consumer))

    # here. I'm starting a separate thread
    t = threading.Thread(target=poll)
    t.start()
    logging.getLogger().info("Thread started")


@events.init.add_listener
def on_locust_init(environment, **kwargs):
    register_kafka_consumer(raw_topic, environment)
```

But according to logs the execution is stuck in `while True` loop.

```
[2022-05-11 17:20:53,309] INFO/locust.main: Starting web interface at http://localhost:8089
[2022-05-11 17:20:53,340] INFO/root: Consumer subscribed to topic 'some_topic': <cimpl.Consumer object at 0x10c28c510>
```

Because there is no `Thread started` log entry.

What am I doing wrong? Is there any approach to overcome this issue?

### EDIT 1

I found [this page](https://docs.locust.io/en/1.4.2/extending-locust.html) in Locust documentation with an example of greenlets usage. Here is what I got now.

```py
def register_kafka_consumer(topic, environment):
    def poll():
        request_type = 'KAFKA_MESSAGE_CONSUMED'
        consumer = Consumer({
            'bootstrap.servers': bootstrap_servers,
            'group.id': group_id
        })
        consumer.subscribe([topic])
        logging.getLogger().info("Consumer subscribed to topic '%s': %s", topic, consumer)
        try:
            while environment.runner.state not in [STATE_STOPPING, STATE_STOPPED, STATE_CLEANUP]:
                time.sleep(1)
                msg = consumer.poll()
                if msg is not None and not msg.error():
                    # diff_millis calculation
                    environment.events.request.fire(
                        request_type=request_type,
                        name=topic,
                        response=msg.value(),
                        response_time=diff_millis,
                    )
        except Exception:
            logging.getLogger().error("Error during polling message for consumer: %s",
                                      str(consumer), exc_info=True)
        finally:
            logging.getLogger().info("Kafka consumer closed: %s", str(consumer))

    if not isinstance(environment.runner, WorkerRunner):
        gevent.spawn(poll)
        logging.getLogger().info("Greenlet started")


@events.init.add_listener
def on_locust_init(environment, **kwargs):
    register_kafka_consumer(raw_topic, environment)
```

According to logs, the Kafka consumer is registered now.

```
[2022-05-12 12:39:03,310] INFO/locust.main: Starting web interface at http://localhost:8089
[2022-05-12 12:39:03,323] NFO/root: Greenlet started
[2022-05-12 12:39:03,323] INFO/locust.main: Starting Locust 2.8.2
[2022-05-12 12:39:03,379] INFO/root: Consumer subscribed to topic 'kafka_topic': <cimpl.Consumer object at 0x111ef4880>
```

Though I cannot open the Web UI now. There is only white screen and infinite loading. Perhaps this grenleet task somehow overoccupied the process. Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/SvenskaSpel/locust-plugins/blob/master/examples/kafka_ex.py (especially the commented out code)

Comment: @Cyberwiz
I've already looked at this plugin. As I can see it, there is only a single message read. But I need to consume new messages during the Locust script executing

Comment: The important thing to take away is the use of greenlets to read the messages. But it was a while ago that I last used that, so I cant say much more without doing a large amount of digging..

Comment: @Cyberwiz
Can you provide an example of using greelets for reading messages in Locust?

Comment: Sorry, I dont have any better examples than the one I gave.

Comment: @Cyberwiz
I made an attempt to implement the consumer as greenlet task. I updated the answer. Please have a look. Do you know the possible cause of the problem?

Comment: Hmm... No I dont see anything obvious that is wrong. I'd try removing stuff in poll() and hopefully find where it is stuck...

Comment: I solved the problem and put the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got it. The problem was caused by this statement:

```py
msg = consumer.poll()
```

There is no timeout. So, Python interpreter waits forever and never gives a chance another thread for execution. But if I set the timeout directly, everything works like a charm. Here is the final version.

```py
def register_kafka_consumer(topic, environment):
    def poll():
        request_type = 'KAFKA_MESSAGE_CONSUMED'
        consumer = Consumer({
            'bootstrap.servers': bootstrap_servers,
            'group.id': group_id
        })
        consumer.subscribe([topic])
        logging.getLogger().info("Consumer subscribed to topic '%s': %s", topic, consumer)
        try:
            while environment.runner.state not in [STATE_STOPPING, STATE_STOPPED, STATE_CLEANUP]:
                time.sleep(1)
                # timeout in seconds
                msg = consumer.poll(timeout=0)
                if msg is not None and not msg.error():
                    # diff_millis calculation
                    environment.events.request.fire(
                        request_type=request_type,
                        name=topic,
                        response=msg.value(),
                        response_time=diff_millis,
                    )
        except Exception:
            logging.getLogger().error("Error during polling message for consumer: %s",
                                      str(consumer), exc_info=True)
        finally:
            logging.getLogger().info("Kafka consumer closed: %s", str(consumer))

    if not isinstance(environment.runner, WorkerRunner):
        gevent.spawn(poll)
        logging.getLogger().info("Greenlet started")


@events.init.add_listener
def on_locust_init(environment, **kwargs):
    register_kafka_consumer(raw_topic, environment)
```

When `consumer.poll()` reaches timeout, it just returns `None` and the loop starts again. Anyway, I still don't understand why Python cannot switch context on `poll` with no timeout. However, the problem is solved now.

Comment: You might want to use timeout=0. If it blocks python/gevent, then using timeout=2 will still block Locust (and any running Users) for 2s which is probably not what you want.

Comment: Good point. It does work with `timeout=0` as well. Updated the anser